# как в языке R преобразовать обект к num

Tags: r

Доброе время суток. Подскажите как преобразовать данные из csv в num 
что бы можно было использовать в cor.test
Читаю данные:

> csv = read.csv('/tmp/data.csv')

```
1  02.01.2017 1443  1  0.1  9.34  6.48  9.34
2  03.01.2017 1361  0  0.0  0.00  6.94  9.44
3  04.01.2017 1562  0  0.0  0.00  7.19 11.23
4  05.01.2017 1490  2  0.1  5.62  7.55 11.25
5  06.01.2017 1433  3  0.2  3.37  7.06 10.11
6  07.01.2017 1554  0  0.0  0.00  6.26  9.73
```

> typeof(csv[2])

```
[1] "list"
```

> typeof(csv[7])

```
[1] "list"
```

пробовал делать так:

> as.numeric(csv[2])

```
Ошибка: объект (список) не может быть преобразован в тип 'double'
```

как преобразовать list в num что бы можно было подсчитать корреляцию использую cor.test ?! 
Если что вот ссылка на csv http://dropmefiles.com/pFANb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно обращаться к листу через **csv$V1**, а не **csv[1]**.

Comment: Спасибо действительно все работает!